# How to prevent maven from duplicating jars in an EAR file?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-ear-plugin

I have an EAR file built by maven and currently I have a commons project which I'd like to put in an EAR\lib, so I used the maven-ear-plugin with the 'bundleDir' tag which works fine, only that now my commons.jar appears in both the lib folder and the EAR root. How do I tell it to put it only in the lib folder?

My pom:

```xml
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>../../outputs/java</outputDirectory>
                <version>5</version>
                <modules>
                    <jarModule>
                        <groupId>com.sample.common</groupId>
                        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
                        <includeInApplicationXml>
                            true
                        </includeInApplicationXml>
                        <bundleDir>/lib</bundleDir>
                    </jarModule>
                    ...
                </modules>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>ear</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And here is the dependency definition:

```xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sample.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I know the title is a bit strange but i had a very long day :)

Comment: can you post your dependency definition about the commons.jar from your pom.xml file, thanks.

Comment: I've updated the main section with the dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your jar file is not ejb you can simply put it to ear dependency without definition into maven-ear-plugin. Otherwise try to setup scope provided to your jar inside the dependency list. This may help.

Comment: The jar is an EJB jar and I've tried with the provided scope, but unfortunately that didn't help.

Comment: May be you also have some another module in your ear dependency list which uses com.sample.common:common scoped compile or runtime. In this case all modules you use in your ear dependency list and dependent on com.sample.common:common should also have scope provided for com.sample.common:common.

Comment: Good point, But I already thought of that and updated all references to that jar and still with no luck.

Comment: I actually revisited all the pom files and found out that I forgot one dependency, so now the jar only appears in th elib folder as planned. Thank you very much.